# Problema ejecutando crontab cada dos minutos utilizando el usuario root

Tags: linux, shell

Tengo un archivo `.sh` muy simple:

```
echo "\nhola" >> /etc/holaadd.txt
```

solo lo ejecuto y se agrega una linea ... mi problema es que quiero adicionarlo al: `/etc/crontab` directamente y lo agregué de la siguiente manera :

```
 */2 * * * * root /bin/hola.sh
```

pero pasan los dos minutos y no se ejecuta verifico el archivo `holaadd.txt` y no se agrega nada.

Comment: Si usas un usuario que no sea root ¿si funciona?

Answer (score 4):

**Verificar archivo crontab**

El archivo `/etc/crontab` tiene que finalizar con una linea en blanco. Si al final del archivo no hay una linea en blanco(es decir, vacia), el señor cron se niega a trabajar.

Ejemplo:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
*/2 *    * * * root /bin/hola.sh
#<--- Esto es una linea en blanco
```

**Comprobar que crontab esta iniciado:**

Después esta la opción de que el servicio no este iniciado, para comprobar que el cron esta iniciado primero pon: `pgrep cron`, si no obtienes respuesta ejecuta `service cron start` (con permisos de root, o en su defecto sudo)

**Invocar el programa con la ruta absoluta:**

Probablemente tu problema radique en que 'supones' que tu programa se ejecutara con sh, pero tienes que tener en cuenta que cron no siempre sabe que tiene que utilizar para ejecutar el comando. Por eso modifica la orden cambiando:

```
 */2 *    * * * root /bin/hola.sh
```

por

```
*/2 *    * * * root /bin/sh /bin/hola.sh
```

*suponiendo que /bin/hola.sh sea la ruta de tu programa y que `/bin/sh` sea la localización de sh. Este último valor lo puedes obtener ejecutando el comando `which sh`.

Comment: Buena respuesta, Hamza. Bienvenido a la parte más de sistemas de [es.so], te invito a pasearte por [tag:linux] y [tag:bash] en busca de cosas del tipo :)

Answer (score 1):

No es recomendable editar `/etc/crontab` directamente.

Las tablas cron se deben editar usando el comando `crontab -e`

Un problema típico con esto es que `vi` es el editor por defecto y no todo el mundo sabe usarlo. Puedes cambiarlo al que más te guste con la variable de entorno `EDITOR`. Por ejemplo :

```
export EDITOR=nano
crontab -e
```

Usando `crontab -e` no corres el riesgo de que `/etc/crontab` sea reescrito sin que te des cuenta y además te avisará si has cometido un error en las líneas que has introducido. Además le permite a los usuarios no root editar su propia tabla.